# Pandas: Transpose/Manipulate Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows. The dataframe describes the makeup of paints, such that the makeup of an arbitrarily named paint (**NAME** column) could be described by mixing specific colors (**subtype** column) in a given percentage (**weight** col) and specific colors can also be differentiated by a generalized parent (**type**). Date is included as a sanity check but is not used here.

```
|weight|NAME       |type  |subtype    |date      |
--------------------------------------------------
|93.35 |candyapple |red   |maroon     |2018-06-30|
|6.65  |candyapple |red   |crimson    |2018-06-30|
|93.41 |grannysmith|green |limegreen  |2010-03-31|
|1.78  |grannysmith|green |deepgreen  |2019-12-31|
|0.72  |grannysmith|yellow|goldyellow |2019-12-31|
|2.96  |grannysmith|brown |lightbrown |2014-10-31|
|33.33 |awfulbrown |red   |maroon     |2020-10-31|
|33.33 |awfulbrown |yellow|plainyellow|2010-06-30|
|33.33 |awfulbrown |green |deepgreen  |2020-02-29|
--------------------------------------------------
```

So `candyapple`'s full makeup is `93.35% crimson` and `6.65% maroon`, which are both subtypes of red. `grannysmith` can be represented by its subtypes as above, but we can also refer to it as by type as `95.19% green`, as the **sum of its green subtypes**, and `0.72% yellow` and `2.96% brown`. Names used for subtypes and types are common across paint configs, but not all configs will list all subtypes. **If a subtype is not listed it is assumed to be 0.00%.** So, for example, we see that `candyapple` has not listed any `green` - we can assume it is `0.00% limegreen`.

1. **Using pandas and python, how can I manipulate this dataframe to fit the following structure?**

```
|NAME       |maroon|crimson|limegreen|deepgreen|goldyellow|lightbrown|maroon|plainyellow|deepgreen|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|candyapple |93.35 |6.65   |0.00     |0.00     |0.00      |0.00      |0.00  |0.00       |0.00     |
|grannysmith|0.00  |0.00   |93.41    |1.78     |0.72      |2.96      |0.00  |0.00       |0.00     |
|awfulbrown |33.33 |0.00   |0.00     |33.33    |0.00      |0.00      |0.00  |33.33      |0.00     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1a. Using pandas, how do I transpose such that values for `subtype` become the column headers and all values are sorted into a single row by `NAME`?

1b. Having transposed, how should I fill any empty spaces in the table with `0.00`? (eg. `candyapple` is `0.00% limegreen`)

2. **Additionally, how could I use pandas to create a similar frame, but for `type` instead of `subtype`? Weighting for type is the sum of weights for its subtypes.**

```
|NAME       |red   |green  |yellow   |brown  |
----------------------------------------------
|candyapple |100.00|0.00   |0.00     |0.00   |
|grannysmith|0.00  |95.19  |0.72     |2.96   |
|awfulbrown |33.33 |33.33  |33.33    |0.00   |
----------------------------------------------
```

2a. Having transposed as in (1), but using `type` this time, how do I use pandas/python to sum the values such that weight for a given `type` will be the sum of weights for its `subtype`?

3. (Added) **Can we combine the two, as below:**

```
|NAME       |red   |green  |yellow   |brown  |maroon|crimson|limegreen|deepgreen|goldyellow|lightbrown|maroon|plainyellow|deepgreen|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|candyapple |100.00|0.00   |0.00     |0.00   |93.35 |6.65   |0.00     |0.00     |0.00      |0.00      |0.00  |0.00       |0.00     |
|grannysmith|0.00  |95.19  |0.72     |2.96   |0.00  |0.00   |93.41    |1.78     |0.72      |2.96      |0.00  |0.00       |0.00     |
|awfulbrown |33.33 |33.33  |33.33    |0.00   |33.33 |0.00   |0.00     |33.33    |0.00      |0.00      |0.00  |33.33      |0.00     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3a. Does pandas have a method to create, from the original dataset, the above combined DF of both aggregated sums of `type` and the individual weights of the `subtypes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case a `pivot` is enough, since there is no aggregation needed:

```
df.pivot('NAME', 'subtype', 'weight').fillna(0)

subtype      crimson  deepgreen  goldyellow  lightbrown  limegreen  maroon  \
NAME                                                                         
awfulbrown      0.00      33.33        0.00        0.00       0.00   33.33   
candyapple      6.65       0.00        0.00        0.00       0.00   93.35   
grannysmith     0.00       1.78        0.72        2.96      93.41    0.00   

subtype      plainyellow  
NAME                      
awfulbrown         33.33  
candyapple          0.00  
grannysmith         0.00
```

For the second case you can use `pivot_table`,  and aggregate with the `sum`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='NAME', columns='type', values='weight', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

type         brown  green     red  yellow
NAME                                     
awfulbrown    0.00  33.33   33.33   33.33
candyapple    0.00   0.00  100.00    0.00
grannysmith   2.96  95.19    0.00    0.72
```

Comment: Awesome, pandas is great. First one failed due to a `duplicate entries in index` error, which I assume is just an error in my dataset. My last question would then be - if I use the second function as above (pivot_table and sum), is there a way to also keep the columns and values for the subtypes? I will update the original question to include part 3.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.crosstab`

```
subtypes = pd.crosstab(df.NAME,df.type,df.weight,aggfunc='sum')

types = pd.crosstab(df.NAME,df.subtype,df.weight,aggfunc='sum')

final = pd.concat([types,subtypes],axis=1)
```

### 1

```
print(subtypes)

subtype      crimson  deepgreen  goldyellow  lightbrown  limegreen  maroon  \
NAME                                                                         
awfulbrown       NaN      33.33         NaN         NaN        NaN   33.33   
candyapple      6.65        NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   93.35   
grannysmith      NaN       1.78        0.72        2.96      93.41     NaN   

subtype      plainyellow  
NAME                      
awfulbrown         33.33  
candyapple           NaN  
grannysmith          NaN
```

### 2

```
print(types)
type         brown   green   red     yellow
NAME                                       
awfulbrown      NaN   33.33   33.33   33.33
candyapple      NaN     NaN  100.00     NaN
grannysmith    2.96   95.19     NaN    0.72
```

### 3

```
print(final.fillna(0))

             brown   green   red     yellow  crimson  deepgreen  goldyellow  \
NAME                                                                          
awfulbrown     0.00   33.33   33.33   33.33     0.00      33.33        0.00   
candyapple     0.00    0.00  100.00    0.00     6.65       0.00        0.00   
grannysmith    2.96   95.19    0.00    0.72     0.00       1.78        0.72   

             lightbrown  limegreen  maroon  plainyellow  
NAME                                                     
awfulbrown         0.00       0.00   33.33        33.33  
candyapple         0.00       0.00   93.35         0.00  
grannysmith        2.96      93.41    0.00         0.00
```